# Google Cloud Function access Cloud SQL PostgreSQL DB timeout

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

This is my Google Cloud Function:

```
async function getPSQLdata() {
  const pg = require('pg');

  var pgConfig = {
    user: 'postgres',
    password: '[MY PASSWORD]',
    database: '[MY DB NAME]',
    host: '[PUBLIC IP ADDRESS OF DB INSTANCE]'
  };

  var pgPool;

  if (!pgPool) {
    pgPool = new pg.Pool(pgConfig);
  }

  const scores = await pgPool
    .query("SELECT * from table")
    .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
    .catch(e => console.error(e.stack));
}

exports.dailyFill = async function main() {
  await getPSQLdata();
};
```

Google Cloud Logging says: "Function execution took 60003 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'".

What I have tried so far:

- I have enabled the Cloud SQL Admin API within the GCP project
- I have enabled the Cloud SQL API within the GCP project
- I have added the Google Cloud Function service account to the IAM as the roles "Cloud SQL Client" and "Project Editor"

Comment: your function should return a promise otherwise it will just timeout. change last statement in `getPSQLdata` to `return pgPool.query("SELECT * from table").then(res =>console.log(res.rows[0])).catch(e => console.error(e.stack));` and export this function as in `exports.dailyFill = getPSQLdata`

Comment: Thx. What do you mean by " export this function as in exports.dailyFill = getPSQLdata"?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functions provides a way you can connect to the DB via Cloud SQL Proxy, see details here https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#public-ip-default_1 this is the preferred method.

The key difference is instead of defining `host` you would use the following

`socketPath: '/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME'`

Comment: Agree with this best practice, you can also use the private IP if you prefer. In any case, using the public IP (open wide I guess) it's absolutely not recommended!

Comment: Juuuust to be sure, did you replace INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME with the connection name from your Cloud SQL instance details? It should be in the format: <project_id>:<region>:<instance_name>